# How to report TFS usage

Tags: tfs

I'm working on implementing TFS for numerous teams and am looking for a way to monitor TFS in terms of how many distinct users, builds ran, work item totals, collections/projects/teams, and more, preferably if I can see daily/weekly/monthly metrics. I've found some solutions by querying the SQL database, but am curious if there are any extensions or solutions others have found to monitor the usage of your TFS instance as well as any GUIs that help visualizations.

Answer (score 0):

No such a comprehensive tool or extension to achieve that.

For specific team project, you can [add widgets to a dashboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/dashboards/add-widget-to-dashboard?view=vsts&tabs=new-query-exp) to monitor the status:

> Widgets smartly format data to provide access to easily consumable
>   data. You add widgets to your team dashboards to gain visibility into
>   the status and trends occurring as you develop your software project.
>
> Each widget provides access to a chart, user-configurable information,
>   or a set of links that open a feature or function.

For example , with builds just specify the specific build definition, for work items you can [create queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/track/using-queries?view=vsts&tabs=new-query-exp) and specify the query when configure a widget.

Actually you can retrieve most of the information via [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/?view=vsts-rest-4.1).

e.g.: [Get Builds - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/builds/list?view=vsts-rest-4.1):

```
GET http://server:8080/tfs/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=3.2
```

You can also try to custom your own reports, please see [SQL Server Reporting (TFS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/sql-reports/?view=tfs-2018) and [Create and manage Reporting Services reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/sql-reports/create-and-manage-reporting-services-reports?view=tfs-2018) for details.